# Как сделать так, чтобы дискорд бот высылал сообщение в чат каждые 10 секунд?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Хочу сделать так, чтобы бот высылал каждые 10 секунд сообщение, пытался переделать код, не получается. Использую библиотеку discord.py.
Вот что у меня имеется:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def notify_task():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    print('Привет')

notify_task.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Не рекомендую код **@OSTEN**, там используется весьма не очень выглядящий `while True` и синхронный `sleep()`.

Вы на правильном пути, не знаю что остановило. Можно сделать так:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="<...>", intents=<...>)


@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def func():
    await bot.get_channel(<channel_id>).send(<...>)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    func.start()


bot.run("<...>")
```

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно что-то подобное:

```
#Импорт нужных библиотек
import discord
import time

from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents

PREFIX = '!'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX)

#Выполняется при запуске бота
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    DiscordComponents(client)
    print('BOT connected')
    #Получаем нужный канал по его ID
    channel = client.get_channel(Channel_ID)
    #Создаем бесконечный цикл в котором каждые 10 секунд в определенный канал посылаем нужное нам сообщение
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        await channel.send("Привет:)")

#Запуск бота
token = ('TOKEN')

client.run(token)
```

Также можно сделать через команду:

```
#При вводе !command происходит нужное вам действие
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True) #Тут мы делаем так, что пользоваться командой могут только администраторы
async def command(ctx):
    #Получаем нужный канал по его ID
    channel = client.get_channel(Channel_ID)
    #Создаем бесконечный цикл в котором каждые 10 секунд в определенный канал посылаем нужное нам сообщение
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        await channel.send("Привет:)")
```

Comment: Почему вы не используете асинхронный модуль?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как его можно использовать для этой задачи